# How can I replace an aluminum window spiral balance?

Tags: windows, aluminum

I would like to replace the spiral balance on my single hung (non removable) aluminum windows but I can't figure out how to remove the clip on the window that the bottom of the spiral hooks into.  There are no screws or attachment points I can see on the outside of the window, so I can't figure out how to remove that clip so I can remove the balance for replacement.  Since the window cannot be removed, I don't know how to go about getting the clip off to replace the balance.

Here are pics of the inside of the window (you can see that the spiral balance just hangs down now.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I question the "non-removable window" premise.

Comment: Oops, sorry - I'd like to see more pictures - of the frame at large, of the individual windows, etc.  Typically a DH window is removable by removing mounting points set inside the window frame.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the spiral balance is a small hole... you will need a tool for this... (look on line and buy one ) it has a small hook on it... move your spiral up by hand until it stops... take  the tool insert tip into hole  and turn the spiral about 10 times... ( clockwise ) ... then using that same tool move the spiral up in to the area that will hold it...( this might not be easy ) but it will kind of be on a ledge that will hold the two small pins... the tension will hold it up... do both sides so the number of times is 10 and giving the same tension on both sides.... slowly raise the window... 
Good luck !